# PrestoDB - connecting to Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, presto

The project I'm working on is using PrestoDB with Oracle and MongoDB.
There is the need to insert a bulk of records (about 5000) in Oracle using the PrestoDB connection in Oracle.

I don't want it to commit each line to have better performances, but if I set autocommit to false, it returns the exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Query failed (#20180831_130756_00032_945ft):
>   Catalog oracle only supports writes using autocommit  at
>   com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.resultsException(PrestoResultSet.java:1803)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.getColumns(PrestoResultSet.java:1747)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.(PrestoResultSet.java:118)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:246)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.execute(PrestoStatement.java:225)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PrestoPreparedStatement.java:104)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PrestoPreparedStatement.java:97)
>
> Caused by: com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Catalog oracle only 
>   supports writes using autocommit  at
>   com.facebook.presto.transaction.TransactionManager$TransactionMetadata.checkConnectorWrite(TransactionManager.java:446)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.transaction.TransactionManager.checkConnectorWrite(TransactionManager.java:222)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.transaction.TransactionManager.getCatalogMetadataForWrite(TransactionManager.java:200)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.metadata.MetadataManager.getCatalogMetadataForWrite(MetadataManager.java:957)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.metadata.MetadataManager.getInsertLayout(MetadataManager.java:574)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LogicalPlanner.createInsertPlan(LogicalPlanner.java:290)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LogicalPlanner.planStatementWithoutOutput(LogicalPlanner.java:184)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LogicalPlanner.planStatement(LogicalPlanner.java:171)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LogicalPlanner.plan(LogicalPlanner.java:144)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LogicalPlanner.plan(LogicalPlanner.java:139)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.doAnalyzeQuery(SqlQueryExecution.java:344)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.analyzeQuery(SqlQueryExecution.java:329)
>     at
>   com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.start(SqlQueryExecution.java:285)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Is it possible, perhaps customizing the plugin, to implement the needed part or does anyone knows if it is a PrestoDB implementation choice?

Does anyone encountered a similar need?

Comment: What Presto Connector to Oracle are you using?

Comment: I downloaded from https://github.com/marcelopaesrech/presto-oracle the sources and adapted them to presto 0.208

Comment: Starburst has a supported Oracle connector, you can reach out to hello@starburstdata.com and ask for a free trial